# Angular project production build has problem importing google fonts

Tags: angular, angular-material, google-fonts

I have an angular project built on latest version 8.2.9. Google fonts works perfectly while on the test environment using `ng serve`. However when I publish the project on the production server the fonts are not loaded.

**style.scss**

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,600');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons');
```

Due to the above mentioned problem the material icons doesn't loads as shown in the image.[image]

However, when I move the above fonts loading statement from global style `style.scss` to `app.component.scss`. It works fine! Any reason why it is not working on the global style? I found something similar to this issue here [ng build/serve --prod ignores scss url imports](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10855)

Comment: Another solution was when I remove the material css file from the array of styles in the angular.json file.

Comment: Does your `angular.json` include your global style sheet in the `styles` option?

Comment: @G.Tranter yes "style.scss" is included along with the material css file as an array. As I said earlier in the comment, when I delete the material css files it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Simply include google fonts into index.html in `<head>` tag instead of any scss or css file.

It will also work for production build.

http://prntscr.com/qx71rf

Comment: This seems like a functional workaround, but it doesn't explain what's going on in the first place.  Any idea of what the problem itself is?